# image не реагирует на resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular

Есть две кноки. Одна из них уменьшает изображение, другая возвращает в прежнее. Я хочу сделать так чтобы Image реагировал на свои изменения размера
`<img (resize)="somefunc">` Пробовал не работает. Как сделать так, чтобы Image реагировал на изменения своего размера.

Comment: Мне кажется Вам нужно вешать событие не на "чтобы Image реагировал на изменения своего размера", а после клика на кнопку что меняет размер, там же в функции и выполнять действие.

Answer (score 1):

Событие `resize` срабатывает исключительно при изменении размера документа. Потому вам надо изменить логику в построении цепочки ивентов и прикрепиться либо к `window.addEventListener('resize')`, либо к результату выполнения какой-то вашей функции, которая меняет размер изображения.